# Wine slow to start when blocked access to network through iptables

Tags: networking, wine, iptables, restricted-access

I've got a separate user for running untrusted applications in wine and it was relieved from accessing network at all by using

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
```

Now, even winecfg on a clean `WINEPREFIX` is slow to start. And it's getting blazingly fast if either regain access to network or the network is down (as in `ifconfig wlan0 down`).

What can I do to still restrict access to network and have the network connectivity on a different user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [Wine needs 127.0.0.1 access](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5695#c1). Use these commands:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -s localhost -m owner --uid-owner username -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
```

You can replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 if you like or need.